# How to find MST of a subset of the vertices in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a graph G = (V, E) and a subset v of V how do you compute a "minimal spanning tree" m that connects all the nodes in v together? That is to say, it can have paths that go through vertices not in v.

My first thought was that m must be a subset of M where M is the MST of G but here is a counter-example through this [diagram](https://jeremykun.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/example-spanning-tree.gif?w=1800): Find the MST of {B, C}. It is clearly the shortest path, the edge with weight 17, which is not a subset of M.

I'm having trouble reducing this problem/defining exactly what to run a classic MST algorithm on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the NP-hard Steiner tree problem. You can 2-approximate by computing an MST using distances between the terminal vertices.

Comment: For some more detail and proofs regarding that 2-approximation, [this set of lecture notes](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs261/lecture02.pdf) does a good job.